# Scaling div background images

Tags: html, css

I have a single png with a variety of social login button images on it. I can get them to display just the images I want by using the following CSS classes:

```
.sign-in-with-facebook {
    width: 430px;
    height: 88px;
    background-image: url("/static/social-media-icons/social-sign-in-buttons.png");
    background-position: -184px -110px;
}
.sign-in-with-google {
    width: 430px;
    height: 88px;
    background-image: url("/static/social-media-icons/social-sign-in-buttons.png");
    background-position: -184px -401px;
}
.sign-in-with-twitter {
    width: 430px;
    height: 88px;
    background-image: url("/static/social-media-icons/social-sign-in-buttons.png");
    background-position: -184px -207px;
}
```

And then adding divs like the following will get my images to appear on my page:

```
<div class="sign-in-with-twitter"></div>
```

First off, is this a reasonable way to handle a "sheet" of images like this?

Second, my main problem is that I want to then scale these buttons down so they're smaller, as they're pretty large in the original png. I've tried playing with `background-size`, `max-width`, `max-height`, wrapping them in another div, etc. with no luck so far. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Yes it is reasonable, then background-size + reset of background-position according to background-size value allows to make responsive backgrounds from sprites  :) here is an example, if this what you look for : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/cxDIh  resize the widow's width to see sprites/background resized

Comment: @GCyrillus Yes, this is close to what I need, but I still can't quite piece it together from your example. If you respond with an answer that puts it a bit more in my specific context, I'll happily accept.

Comment: @Trix sure, I guess I can always change the accepted answer if GCyrillus responds with something better. The reason I wasn't accepting right away is because unanswered questions are more likely to draw further responses, which is what I was hoping for. Similarly, on your end, I'd ask that you please upvote any questions you answer (like mine) that's well-asked and potentially valuable for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes! this is a reasonable way named [Spriting](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)
2. The best way is to downsize it, using some raster editing tool (like photoshop)

Comment: My issue with this is that it won't scale properly when on a mobile device (i.e. it's not responsive). @GCyrillus's comment is closer to what I need, but not quite there.

Comment: As in ur question u told "Problem  is that I want to scale those buttons down as they are pretty large in the original image". If you have problem in mobile or responsive problems, please consider asking new questions